# How to set AutoHeight of UITableViewCell with two prototypes in one UITableView using AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uikit

I have UITableView with **two** cell prototypes. It looks like:

[image]
[image]

I know, that for autoheight I need to add some constraints, `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, etc. I have already done it in another controller. But I can't find actually (I have beed searching for long time), how to do the same with 2 prototypes in one `tableView`?

So, **the question is**: How to make it with Autolayout (not `height for row at index path`)? Or maybe I should use some libs, like `IGListKit` etc.?

Comment: Are you able to show each prototype, just not getting the sizing correct? Or are you not even able to show the 2 different prototype cells yet?

Comment: @DonMag Both of them appear, but they are not sizing correct.

Comment: You are getting a error in your autolayout, see the red arrow in the top right

Comment: OK... have you successfully auto-sized *one* cell type?

Comment: @DonMag I have another controller. It has self-sizing cells. But i can't do the same with two prototypes cells.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't matter at all if you have 1, 2 or 20 different prototype cells. If they are each setup correctly - proper constraints, etc - then they will all auto-size correctly. Check your constraints and see if you have any that need to be fixed (the red-arrow indicates that yes, you have constraint / layout errors).

Comment: @DonMag Thx. Trying

Comment: @VladPulichev - better to have an answer with a resolution than to delete the question (even if it was a "whoops" type of question :)

Comment: @DonMag Its some kind of "Woops" as you said, but I thought, that I had never seen a self sizing cells with two prototypes. And all tutorials with only one prototype.. Stupid question anyway. But thx!

Comment: @JoséNeto thx you too, Mr:)

Comment: @VladPulichev no problem mate! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image indicates you have some invalid / incomplete constraints. If you fix those, auto-sizing should work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any code to achieve automatic dimension, all you need to do in code is to set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 440` in `viewDidLoad()`. any positive number would do for estimated row height.

In storyboard, you must ensure the cell layout is non-breaking in a top-down orientation using layout constraints. For example, in your posted image, two image views one the left and on the right, must somehow have a distance from the `contentView` top (or its margin). For the image views, their heights also need to be defined. The label 'date' should have some distance from the images then a distance to the bottom (or its margin) of `contentView`, hence the layout from cell top to bottom is not ambiguous.

Note that if you are using UILabel, depending on the label text, width and height are implied and calculated. To achieve the best result of your use case, content compression resistance priority and hugging priority may also be useful to you.

Comment: Thx for answer!